# gatsby-remark-relative-images error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby

I'm getting a weird error when I run develop on my site and it's preventing me from being able to build my site and send it to deploy. I'm not sure how to solve this, does anyone know how to fix this issue?

When I run my develop command I get this error:

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-remark-relative-images" threw an error while running the onCreateNode lifecycle:

The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined



  Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
  
  - validators.js:124 validateString
    internal/validators.js:124:11
  
  - on-create-node.js:15 Object.exports.onCreateNode
    [portfolio]/[gatsby-remark-relative-images]/dist/on-create-node.js:15:42
  
  - api-runner-node.js:487 runAPI
    [portfolio]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:487:22
  
  - api-runner-node.js:638 Promise.catch.decorateEvent.pluginName
    [portfolio]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:638:13
  
  - debuggability.js:384 Promise._execute
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9
  
  - promise.js:518 Promise._resolveFromExecutor
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:518:18
  
  - promise.js:103 new Promise
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:103:10
  
  - api-runner-node.js:636 
    [portfolio]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:636:16
  
  - util.js:16 tryCatcher
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
  
  - reduce.js:166 Object.gotValue
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:166:18
  
  - reduce.js:155 Object.gotAccum
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/reduce.js:155:25
  
  - util.js:16 Object.tryCatcher
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
  
  - promise.js:547 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:547:31
  
  - promise.js:604 Promise._settlePromise
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:604:18
  
  - promise.js:649 Promise._settlePromise0
    [portfolio]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:649:10
```

The development build will still work, but the error prevents a successful deployment. I'm really not sure what to do to fix this. Is there something wrong with my nodejs installation?

This is what my gatsby-config file looks like:

```
require("dotenv").config()
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: ``,
    description: ``,
    author: ``,

  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        spaceId: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
        // Learn about environment variables: https://gatsby.dev/env-vars
        accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
      options: {
          plugins: [
              'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
              {
                  resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
                  options: {
                      maxWidth: 750,
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
          name: 'src',
          path: `${__dirname}/src/`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `Heebo`,
          `Open Sans` // you can also specify font weights and styles
        ],
        display: 'swap'
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        icon: 'src/assets/images/favicon-32x32.png',
      },
    },
    
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    'gatsby-plugin-sass',
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
  ],
}
```

Comment: Fixed by utilizing this plugin instead <https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2/>

Comment: Please don't add comments using my answer resolution. Consider accepting/upvoting or even give feedback to the one that really answered the question because it took an effort researching, reading/understanding your question(s) and answer them

Answer (score 1):

You have two implementations of `require('dotenv')`. Remove one of them and leave the code as:

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})
```

Because in your previous definition, the first instance of `dotenv` haven't a `path` defined, hence it was breaking your compilation.

I'd recommend using [`gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2`](https://gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2) plugin instead of the one you're using (v1).

Comment: Thanks! I fixed this, but the error is still occurring. Could it be something else as well?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-relative-images-v2/?

Comment: Please don't add answers using my own. Consider accepting/upvoting the one that really answered it because it took us an effort researching and the reading/understanding of your question(s)